# CloudRun can't make outbound http(s) requests - Timeout

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-networking, google-cloud-http-load-balancer

I'm having a hard time debugging why cloudrun is not allowed to make outbound HTTP to the public internet.

My setup follows a simple Global loadbalancer (Classic) ->  CloudRun, Using a custom VPC Network and a serverless VPC connector explained here:

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#create-connector

I can reach my Cloudrun service just fine by hitting the URL in the browser, however, my server is making an HTTP request to a public endpoint which fails with a timeout.

I've also tested by hitting different public URLs (ex: Wikipedia) and the same error happens. So it is definitely an egress issue.

I've added a custom egress policy to see if that was the issue, (as shown below) but that didn't make any difference.

[image: Egress]

Here is my Entire Networking Configuration to make things easier to understand:

#### Network

name: virtual-applications
Subnet Gateway: 10.7.10.0/28

[image: Network]

#### Firewall Rules

[image: Firewall Rules]

**Note**: I've also tried to change the "allow-internal" rule, to allow all (0.0.0.0/0) no difference.

#### Routes

[image: Routes]

#### VPC Peering

[image: VPC Peering]

#### VPC Connector

[image: Connector]

Any idea?

Comment: do you have more detail with your code? If it doesn't work without the serverless VPC Connector, it's a code issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Problem was that I needed to create a NAT gateway by assigning static IP

Here is the guide: [https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20a%20Cloud%20Run%20service%20connects%20to,database%20or%20API%20using%20an%20IP%20address-based%20firewall](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20a%20Cloud%20Run%20service%20connects%20to,database%20or%20API%20using%20an%20IP%20address-based%20firewall).